# stringWithBytes: length: encoding: is producing the wrong length of string

Tags: ios, nsstring, byte

I'm trying to produce a string from an array of bytes in objective c. Within my class, i define the following constant char

```
static const char HELLO_WORLD[] = {0x68,0x65,0x6c,0x6c,0x6f,0x20,0x77,0x6f,0x72,0x6c,0x64,0x0d,0x0a};
```

I then have a method in MyClass that looks like this:

```
+ (NSString *)stringFromBytes:(const void*)bytes
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:(sizeof(bytes)/sizeof(bytes[0])) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

if I call the method by doing this

```
[MyClass stringFromBytes:HELLO_WORLD];
```

I get a string that looks like "hell" - im not sure if i'm doing the length part of this correctly, and im assuming thats the issue. Any guidance on how to get that working?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
+ (NSString *)stringFromBytes:(const char[])charbytes length:(NSUInteger)length
{
  return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:charbytes length:length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Use like this:

```
 NSString *str = [MyClass stringFromBytes:HELLO_WORLD length:sizeof(HELLO_WORLD)];
 NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: unfortunately that brings up an incompatible pointer type error (sending 'const char [9]' to parameter of type 'char'). Replacing const char with just char or char* doesnt work either..

Comment: the error popping up is now 'sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'const char *' instead of 'const char []'

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
+ (NSString *)stringFromBytes:(const void*)bytes
```

method, `bytes` is just a pointer and therefore `sizeof(bytes) == 4`, which explains why you see the "hell".

A pointer has no information about the size of the structure it points to. You must either provide the size as an additional argument, or work with NULL-terminated C strings.

Comment: up vote since this helped me understand what was going on. Thanks!